# Are the services managed by systemd implemented based on sockets?

Tags: systemd, services

Are all (or most) of the services managed by systemd (or sysvinit) implemented based on sockets (either internet or unix domain sockets)?

I have this question, because I am not sure what the concept "service" is. I guess it means a server that  communicates  with its clients via sockets?

Thanks.

Comment: No strictly defined concept.  For systemd, it's the . service units, or say the corresponding runtime cgroups. Services are implemented all by their own, sockets may or may not be involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A systemd service is just something that systemd can run and manage.  So, for example, `systemd-firstboot.service` is a service that is started the first time after the system is installed, and it performs some configuration, then stops.  `systemd-fsck-root.service` will check the root disk on reboot.  And so on.

A fair number of services act as servers (eg `cups.service`) but not all.

From `man systemd.service`

```
   A unit configuration file whose name ends in .service encodes
   information about a process controlled and supervised by systemd.
```